# How can a I sum a list in cycles

Tags: python, list, sum

I need to create a list that sums values in ranges from x to x. For example, calculate the sum 2 by 2

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
listSum = sum(myList)
print(f"Sum of list -> {listSum}")
```

I want to achieve in the first iteration 1+2, in the next 3+4 until the last list value. I tried with a list compreension but i don't know how to do the sum.

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list2 = [ i for i in range(myList[0],len(myList),2)]
print(list2)
```

I pretend obtain list2 = [3,7,11,15,19]

The problem em questions is ,for example, if my list has 240 values, I want to sum 60 in 60, sum in blocks of 60 values.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting any leftover values? Like length 15 in blocks of 4?
Ill answer this with just basic python, if you want to use numpy look at AJITHs answer.

```
list2 = [sum(myList[i:i+blockSize]) for i in range(len(myList)//blockSize +1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is first split the original list in question in parts of size 'n'.
this can be done by using list comprehension to create a list of parts of the original list.

```py
>>> original_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> n = 2 # size of each chunk
>>> splits_of_og_list = [original_list[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(original_list), n)]
>>> splits_of_og_list
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

replace `n` to whatever size you want and you will get chunks of size `n`.

then simply use the sum function over the `splits_of_og_list`.

```py
>>> summed_list = [sum(split) for split in splits_of_og_list]
>>> summed_list
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
```

`sum` is an inbuilt function that returns the total of a iterable of integers.

Answer (score 0):

The `range(start, stop, step)` function can take a step which allows you to skip over values as you iterate. You then need to index the elements in myList using the iterated value.

```py
>>> myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list2 = [myList[i-1] + myList[i] for i in range(1, len(myList), 2)]
>>> list2
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
```

Note that when there is an odd number of elements in `myList`, the last element is missed.

```py
>>> myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> list2 = [myList[i-1] + myList[i] for i in range(1, len(myList), 2)]
>>> list2
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
```

Comment: I think I wasn't enlightening enough, I want to sum the list in blocks, for example if my list has 240 values, I want to sum 60 in 60, sum in blocks of 60 values.

Comment: So you're saying, you want to obtain the overall sum, but in stages where each stage reduces the list size by a factor of 2?

Comment: Or other factor, I have a list of values and I wanto to sum the first 60, 0 to 59, then 60 to 119 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy

```
import numpy as np

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
arr = np.reshape(np.array(myList), (-1, 2))
sum_arr = np.sum(arr, axis=1)
print(sum_arr)
```

Output:

```
[ 3  7 11 15 19]
```